# Meta property não está funcionando no face

Tags: html, html-meta-tag

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de html, porém quando posto minha url no facebook, não abre a imagem com o título. Porém no twitter funciona perfeitamente.

Eu color a **url** `www.maisguarapari.com.br` no face não exibe imagem. Não tenho nem ideia o por que isso está acontecendo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="author" content="Gladison Luciano Perosini">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:480px)" href="/css/smartphone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:999px)" href="/css/tablet-novo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1000px) and (max-width:1566px)" href="/css/tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1567px)" href="/css/pc.css">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br" hreflang="pt-br" />

<title>Mais Guarapari - O Portal da cidade de Guarapari - ES</title>
<meta name="description" content="O maior e o mais completo portal da cidade de Guarapari. O Mais Guarapari é o Guia Comercial da cidade, com hotéis, pousadas, restaurantes, imóveis e muito mais">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<base href="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br" />
<meta name="Robots" content="index, follow">




<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Mais Guarapari - O Portal da cidade de Guarapari - ES">
<meta property="og:description" content="O maior e o mais completo portal da cidade de Guarapari. O Mais Guarapari é o Guia Comercial da cidade, com hotéis, pousadas, restaurantes, imóveis e muito mais">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/img/meta/maisguarapari.png">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="167340017360987" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@gladisonlp">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mais Guarapari - O Portal da cidade de Guarapari - ES">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="O maior e o mais completo portal da cidade de Guarapari. O Mais Guarapari é o Guia Comercial da cidade, com hotéis, pousadas, restaurantes, imóveis e muito mais">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/img/meta/maisguarapari.png">
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Mais Guarapari - O Portal da cidade de Guarapari - ES">
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, o Facebook, faz um cache das URLs. Se você fez um teste onde a imagem não estava informada, depois corrigiu e testou novamente, a antiga ainda pode ser apresentada.

Você pode utilizar o [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing). Ao informar seu site, a url será validada novamente e os dados atualizados.

Poderá ver que agora a imagem está [correta](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maisguarapari.com.br%2F).

Comment: A URL principal funcionou, mas a https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/noticias/33/guarapari-atrai-milhares-de-turistas-todos-os-anos assim como qualquer outra que não seja a principal não funciona.